# conventional wisdom Jquery: how do I know I have selected etc

Tags: jquery

Learning jquery right now though I guess this question could be true of any programming language.

I'll ask the question by example:

Currently reading "jquery fundamentals". In the exercises one of the questions is "Figure out how many elements on the page are hidden (hint: .length)."

I've written the code "$('html :hidden').length;"

At this stage I did not know the output. To know if I had written the right code I then wrote:

"var hidden = $('html :hidden').length;

$('h3').html(hidden);"

The h3 changed to "8" which told me that there are 8 hidden elements on the page. Changing the h3 element to find out that I had done something correctly seems a bit crude. Is there a conventional way to know if you have either selected an object correctly or to know a value without actually writing on the html doc?

Comment: Are you wanting to know if you've selected it properly _while debugging/writing your code_ or in production? The two situations are subtlely different.

Comment: I suppose for now the situation would be production

Comment: Grim...'s answer is a great approach for production, as the user will see nothing unless she is running a console (which is very rare).

Answer (score 8):

The old-school way was

```
alert(variable);
```

But much better if you're using a browser with Web Developer functions built in (like Chrome, or IE8+):

```
console.log(variable);
```

In Chrome, you open the console (where the logs will appear) with CTRL+Shift+J.

You could even type your jQuery straight into the console. For example, on this 'answer' page,  typing

```
$("html:hidden").length
```

returns 0.

If you're using Firefox, get the Firebug plugin. I honestly can't remember how I developed without them.

Comment: I use firebug as a newbie. Could you elaborate on how to use console.log? Do I type console.log from within firebug or on the js doc? Thanks for help too

Comment: You put it in the Javascript file. Alternatively, like I said, just type the code '$("html:hidden").length' into the console.

Comment: Take a read of 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console' (like some other people have mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use -

```
console.log(hidden)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console

You could also use

```
alert(hidden)
```

but that will display a message box for each debug statement, which may prove more disruptive than writing to the html doc. `console.log` also has the advantage of being able to output the contents of more complex object such as arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [alert](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) or [console.log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Two methods are typically used:

1. `alert("[YourValue]");`
2. `console.log("[YourValue]");`

**Additional Information:**

MDN: [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console)
MDN: [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert)